# message sent to released object (never released manually)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmediaitem, nszombieenabled

Removed release statements. Some of them seemed to be okay, but that was probably just because other things were exploding first.

---

```
- (void)handleNowPlayingItemChanged:(id)notification {
    MPMediaItem *item = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
    NSString *title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];

    NSNumber *duration = [item
                         valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
    float totalTime = [duration floatValue];
    progressSlider.maximumValue = totalTime;

    CGSize artworkImageViewSize = self.albumCover.bounds.size;
    MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [item valueForProperty:
                                                   MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    if (artwork) {
        self.albumCover.image = [artwork imageWithSize:artworkImageViewSize];
    } else {
        self.albumCover.image = nil;
    }

    titleLabel.text = title;

    /*OpenEars stuff*/
}
```

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346079/error-getting-artwork-for-current-song) I mention the SQLite errors concerning artwork.

** Deleted error and details concerning NSZombieEnabled alert of call to released objects. **

---

Well don't I feel stupid. It was all memory management.
I put effort into not leaking anything, even in a temporary solution, and yet I did this...

Comment: Have you tried profiling with Zombies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you provide I do not see any calls to retain, alloc/init, or some variation of copy. That means that you should not have a any calls to release in that method and that will be the cause of your crash. Make sure you are not over releasing in other methods and remember the [basics of memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html).

Comment: I usually call `new` and then assign something, but I didn't this time. Simple confusion. // Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're releasing title and artwork, but they're not yours. This will lead, soon or later, to a tentative to release an already deallocated object (from item's dealloc or somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

// [artwork release];

//[title release];

comment those since those are autoreleased object