# How can i do text to speech with Female voice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text-to-speech

I developed a text to speech application in objective c for iPad.

I used `Flite` class (OPenears Library)to do it. But my client is not happy because he need some good quality sound with high volume. Also he need a **Female** voice for text to speech.

I searched every where to do the above thing. Can any one help me to do it. How can i get text to speech in Female voice? Any sample codes or links to refer...

Comment: Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone

Comment: i need to know that is there any libraries supporting female voice?

Comment: not getting any female voice..all are in Male voice..help me brilliant guys.........

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6347072/412916

Comment: same not getting any female voice.......

Comment: At least the google and acapela products have a female voice. I don't remember the others, but it's likely.

Comment: All of the packages linked in the referenced threads have female voices, some of them a few.

Answer (score 2):

All of the TTS libraries for iOS have female voices. In the libraries that use Flite, the voices with "slt" in them are female. I think that in the commercial libraries/APIs, they are labeled with women's names.

Can you give an example of a TTS library for iOS that you need help setting a female voice for?

By the way, I don't want to encourage you to use OpenEars if it isn't a fit for you, but your OpenEars installation sounds like it's misconfigured -- the documentation could help you with fixing your volume issue and using the higher-quality female voice than the default.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.politepix.com/forums/topic/please-test-this-experimental-multithreaded-flitecontroller-w-speedpitchvar/

Check This one out fantastic one..

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you checked this out ?

https://bitbucket.org/Politepix/openearsextras/src
it was useful to me.might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use iOS7

In the .h file
You need to use AVFoundation

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *mySpeech = @"This is an Apple";

    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance =
    [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:mySpeech];
    utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate / 7.0f;
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"]; // defaults to your system language
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```