# TTS Google api Xcode 4.x

Tags: xcode, mp3, avaudioplayer, text-to-speech

I've a problem with google TTS api.
Well, I think that with the api everything it is ok because if I use the path of my desktop and I run the app in the simulator, it create the file with the mp3.
The problem is I can't reproduce it. 
I have no error, but I can't ear nothing. I use AVaudioPlayer.
This is the code I use:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.mp3"];

NSString *text = @"You are one chromosome away from being a potato.";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%@",text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

AVAudioPlayer  *player;
NSError        *err;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) 
{    
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&err];
    player.volume = 0.4f;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player setNumberOfLoops:0];
    [player play];    
}
```

I get this code from another stackoverflow question : [Text-to-speech on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347072/text-to-speech-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `AVAudioPlayer` is not a class variable. Try to promote it, and try again. Good luck