# Text-to-speech libraries for iPhone

Tags: iphone, libraries, text-to-speech

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text to speech on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone)

How do I get started with text-to-speech conversion in [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone)?

I want to read the text typed by the user. Are there any available libraries or demos? I have gone through some of them, but I didn't understand where to start it from.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For online,you can use my **[Google-TTS-Library-For-iOS](https://github.com/shamsudheen/Google-TTS-Library-For-iOS)** to achieve your goal.

Offline **iPhone TTS** implementation is easy to do. You can see the details [here](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/).

There are many paid and free **iOS TTS libraries** are available .

They are ,

#### Free (Offline/Online)

- [iphone-tts](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src)  Note: read "HOW TO USE" section .
- [TTSOverview-iOS](https://github.com/meredian/TTSOverview-iOS)
- [flite-1.4-iphone](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/src/a6502c779cd3/flite-1.4-iphone/)
- [Openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/#)
- [cmu.edu](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/)
- [RJGoogleTTS](https://github.com/hbashirNaij/RJGoogleTTS)
- [VocalKit](https://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit)

#### Paid (Online)

- [iSpeech iOS SDK](https://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone) (TTS and ASR)
- [nuance Dragon-dictation](http://www.nuance.com/index.htm)
- [Acapala](http://www.acapela-group.com/text-to-speech-interactive-demo.html)
- [ivona](http://developer.ivona.com/)
- [neospeech](http://www.neospeech.com/tts-engine.aspx)

Comment: Google TTS works only for short sentences. Do you have a clue why?

Comment: Yup.. Its maximum supported text length is 100 characters. So split-up ur long sentence in to parts(each contains 100 characters) , store in to an array and pass one by one to the TTS method.

Comment: @Idan: I have edited my answer.. or look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057961/using-google-text-to-speech-tts-api-on-ios/16095785#16095785

Comment: neo speech does not seem to be free

Comment: thanks for this post ramshad. do you know if any TTS engines, including AVSpeechSynthesizer, allow you to use custom voices?

Comment: according to this post apple now offers TTS out of the box with AVSpeechSynthesizer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone