# text to speech iphone app

Tags: ios

Good Evening,

I'm looking for a simple text to speech for iphone app development.  I see numerous posts about this including ...

[Text-to-speech libraries for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839671/text-to-speech-libraries-for-iphone/12839821#12839821)

Question though, this link is all third party developers to use text to speech.  I thought apple has a class reference to create speech?  (nsspeechsynthesizer)  Can someone please explain?  Does apple not provide this for us?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 Text To Speech Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561926/ios-7-text-to-speech-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSSpeechSynthesizer works fine on Mac.VSSpeechSynthesizer is available for the iOS - but it is a private API and as such will likely be rejected from the app store. However you can still make apps for private consumption. I consider this a bug as it makes creating accessible apps for the partially sighted for instance, harder. I have filed Bug ID #: 9451650 Bug Title: VSSpeechSynthesizer is Private.

Comment: so as of now apple doesnt offer a class for us to use in app thats will be included in app store?

Comment: if I use a free non-private api, will apple reject it from store?

Comment: Apple will not reject it if you use a free non-private api.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 7 has the AVSpeechSynthesizer class

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, Apple does not include NSSpeechSynthesizer in iOS, only in Mac OS X.