# iOS Text To Speech Api

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, siri

I can't seem to find anything on this.  Are there any Siri classes or API's in iOS7 that let you do text to speech?  All I am trying to do is something like the following:

```
[siriInstance say:@"This is a test"];
```

And then have Siri say it from my app.

It seems we should be capable of doing this, no?  Seems like a trivial thing.

Comment: There is no API for Siri

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Since iOS 7 you have a new TTS Api.

**In Objective C**

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Some text"];
[utterance setRate:0.2f];
[synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

**In Swift**

```
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Some text")
utterance.rate = 0.2
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

You can also change the voice like this :

```
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "fr-FR")
```

And then speek

- **In Swift 2**
  `synthesizer.speakUtterance(utterance)`
- **In Swift 3**
  `synthesizer.speak(utterance)`

Don't forget to `import AVFoundation`

**Helpful methods**

You can Stop or Pause all speech using these two methods :

```
- (BOOL)pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:(AVSpeechBoundary)boundary;
- (BOOL)stopSpeakingAtBoundary:(AVSpeechBoundary)boundary;
```

The `AVSpeechBoundary` indicates if the speech should pause or stop immediately (`AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate`) or it should pause or stop after the word currently being spoken (`AVSpeechBoundaryWord`).

Check the [AVSpeechSynthesizer Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This answer save my time, Thanks.

Comment: All of this can be encapsulated into a helper class for doing TTS: https://vijayt.com/post/text-to-speech-in-ios7/

Comment: @vijayst yes, why not :-)

Answer (score 9):

This is Ali ABBAS' answer for use in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import PlaygroundSupport

var str = "Hello, playground"

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: str)
utterance.rate = 0.4
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

//for playground only
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = playerViewController.view
//

synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never done any work specifically with Siri. I may be wrong, but I think integrating with Siri is very difficult using private API's.

I would take a look at the openears framework for IOS. I have done some basic work with this in the past and it does both offline speech recognition and synthesized speech/text-to-speech

Hope [this](http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial/) helps you.

Comment: were you able to add new voices with openears?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/jonbarlo/iPhoneTTSSampleApp) you will find a text to speech (TTS) sample app (Objective-C) based on [this](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/)