# How to use iOS 10 Speech Recognition?

Tags: ios, core-audio, speech, ios10

How to transcribe audio into text in iOS10 using Speech.framework?

Answer (score 8):

Its very simple, just few lines of code.

```
let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()  
let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioFileURL)
recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error)   in  
     if let error = error {
        print("There was an error: \(error)")
     } else {
        print (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)
     }
})
```

NOTE:
As with accessing other types of protected data, such as Calendar and Photos data, performing speech recognition requires the user’s permission (for more information about accessing protected data classes, see Security and Privacy Enhancements).

In the case of speech recognition, permission is required because data is transmitted and temporarily stored on Apple’s servers to increase the accuracy of speech recognition. To request the user’s permission, you must add the **NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription** key to your app’s Info.plist file.

Refer: http://saravnandm.blogspot.in/2016/06/ios10-speech-recognition-in-ios-10_23.html

Comment: Vow ! Is it really this much simple ?

Comment: yes apple made it very simple now. No need to use any third party frameworks.

Comment: Anything like text to speech available as part of apple's framework ?

Comment: Its available from ios 7 onwards. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561926/ios-7-text-to-speech-api

Comment: No, you need an internet. As of now there is no offline support.

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM, No, it's not! That question is about TTS, not Speech to text.

Comment: I encountered the following error: `Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Cannot initialize an instance of AVAssetReader with an asset at non-local URL '/Users/.../CoreSimulator/Devices/3A...997/data/Containers/Data/Applicati ... ehEB.wav'`. Any idea?