# xamarin cross platform map with turn by turn

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

We have a need in our app where the user will get turn by turn navigation to a location then need the ability to tell the app, "hey I'm here, don't need the turn by turn anymore."

Obviously I'm trying to stay cross platform. I tried this control which extends on Forms.Maps:

https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap

It's closer, but it doesn't do actual turn by turn, it draws a path between 2 pins then exposes a list of instructions with no location tracking, so it won't fit the requirement.

Then I found the openuri method here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/maps/map-navigation/

That works GREAT. The only issue is the application completely disappears. I get this is expected behavior from openuri, but I can't find any other way to get the full on turn by turn guided navigation. Is anyone aware of any way I could use guided navigation and expose a button, or anything really, like a button that says "Dismiss Map" and returns to the application? I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Thanks.

Comment: You would need to Query the Google Directions API and display a Polyline on a Map in your app https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/   Use GPS to track the user location on the path and use the Text To Speech API to talk to the user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561926/ios-7-text-to-speech-api

Comment: You might take a look at Microsofts MyDriving app ([link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/campaigns/mydriving/)). Look at the video to see that it does tracking though not necessarily turn by turn. Also the project on GitHub is in Xamarin iOS and Android, not Forms.