# High Quality Text-To-Speech SDK for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, text-to-speech

I've been looking for a High Quality TTS library for iOS. The best one I found is OpenEars which is free and very recommended but the sound is too metallic for my needs.

Does anyone can recommend of a really good quality TTS library (even not free one) for iOS? Something that would sound like Siri or more like human...

Thanks!

Comment: see the available SDK's list here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839671/text-to-speech-libraries-for-iphone/12839821#12839821  from the list acapela is nice one..You can check it out its quality in "Proloquo2GO" iPad app. or you can also use the Google TTS in iOS too.. all details are available in my answer..

Comment: For some reason Google TTS API works only on short sentences. Do you know how to solve?

Answer (score 5):

Here are but a few:

[Flite](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/) port for iOS.

[Acapela](http://www.acapela-for-iphone.com)

[VocalKit](https://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit)

[Ivona](http://developer.ivona.com)

These all have their upside and downside, quality of the voice and speech patterns vary. As well as how easy they are to implement. But hopefully one of them will be to your liking.