# How to use Speech Recognition inside the iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, siri

I know that there is no public API for the SIRI-Services,
but is there an API for simple Speech-Recognition?  So if I have a textfield and the user taps onto that textfield, a keyboard with the typically microphone button appears and if he pressed it the speech get recognized and transformed into a string object? Or is this button maybe presented by default?

Comment: This below is two speech api http://www.politepix.com/openears/    && http://www.ispeech.org/

Comment: Check [Text to speech on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839671/text-to-speech-libraries-for-iphone

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of TTS questions.  This question is asking how to convert speech into text, not the other way around.

Comment: Checkout GIRI: https://github.com/jhurt/GIRI. Disclaimer: I wrote it.

Comment: You should tell us what languages shall be recognized.

Comment: Apple introduced Speech Recognition in iOS10 -> ```let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioFileURL)
recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
     print (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)
})```

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida, Yeah, but code you put here that is for preRecorded audio files

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest will be helpful for you. Its objects records and buffers the audio data while you are giving input. So your buffered data can be given to the SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida :http://mindbowser.com/blog/siri-speech-to-text/ refer this for more information

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are many libraries availble. You can use any of them.

1. [openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) // This is the best library
2. [VocalKit](https://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit) (Deprecated for open ears)
3. [TTS](https://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/)
4. [ispeech](https://www.ispeech.org/developers/iphone) (Not free)

Hope it helps you.

**NOTE**:

if you download [openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) (*which contains a sample project called "OpenEarsSampleApp"*) @efimovD mentions this

> Check the code in view controller and you will see an array with
>   possible commands. This thing detects commands! Not some talk. It
>   listens and tries to compare what you've said with the words from
>   array

Comment: It seems openear's sample app always thinks I am repeating the word "GO". Fails completely. Using iPhone 6+ with 8.1.2

Comment: You can also consider CeedVocal (not free) which has been used in many apps on iOS. https://github.com/creaceed/CeedVocal  and http://www.creaceed.com/ceedvocal

Comment: Is TTS for speech recognition or only for text-to-speech? If only for the latter one, please remove it from the list.

Comment: which one is best for indian accent ?

Comment: I checked the docs and made an edit. TTS does indeed do TTS only and not recognition.

Comment: @ruralcoder Yes, this is because you don' t understand what it does. Check the code in view controller and you will see an array with possible commands. This thing detects commands! Not some talk. It listens and tries to compare what  you've said with the words from array. The best comparison will be displayed.

Comment: http://www.ispeech.org/#/home/ claims iSpeech is free and open-source for Mobile use..?

Comment: You can find sample app for TTS over here ---> https://github.com/jonbarlo/iPhoneTTSSampleApp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MindMeld iOS SDK provided by Expect Labs.  It supports continuous (streaming) speech recognition on iOS. It also supports natural language understanding and content discovery for any custom content domain.

Try it out at:  https://expectlabs.com/docs/sdks/ios/gettingStarted

Comment: To the suggester: you shouldn't do that, the link should be left as is, because the reader could understand where are they going to click.