# Swift: how to implement speech recognization in my app?

Tags: swift, ipad, speech-recognition

I am developing an app which is in swift language. In my app there are some commands to recognize and perform action on it. for eg. while speaking 'Back' the word can be recognize and performs back action on that page.

I am searched on it but can't helps me

Please provide some guide line or an help or comment will be appreciated Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Speech Recognition inside the iOS SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812399/how-to-use-speech-recognition-inside-the-ios-sdk)

Comment: I was checked that link but can't help me for swift.

Comment: You can use C and Objective-C APIs from Swift.

Comment: In that link there the libraries to use speech recognization (iSpeech and opwnEra) but i am new in coding so i didn't undersatand how to use openEra library? apart from this any other solution Please?