# Is there a way to use iOS/Siri voice to text capabilities to add a voice interface into an app?

Tags: ios, voice-recognition

For example, I would like to build an app to remind me to pick up a kid from daycare. I'd like to touch a button inside the app and dictate instructions that "Daycare closes at 3pm tomorrow" and I can then process the text rather than making them select from pulldowns. Is this possible in some iOS kit?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812399/how-to-use-speech-recognition-inside-the-ios-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A speech recognition API is shipping with Xcode 8.

[WWDC Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/509/)

[Example Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Introduction/Intro.html)

You can download the beta build now or wait till it ships this fall.

Comment: My understanding was that SiriKit if for triggering an app via Siri and is only for certain domains like booking a ride. I just want to use the voice-to-text feature inside a running app.

Comment: I think that's actually right. However it looks like they are shipping a speech recognition API separate from SiriKit. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/509/  an example project: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thanks for that link